# Is the puzzling icon too big in the SE app?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

As seen below, the Puzzling icon is very big compared to other sites' icons.
[image]

Is this intended or is it just abnormally large? Or am I just crazy?

Comment: Same in android app, probably API bug and the apps don't restrict the size for some odd reason.

Comment: They might have picked the wrong size icons because there's a [similar problem on the main StackExchange page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285146/site-icons-displayed-in-wrong-sizes) with hot questions where 48px icons have different sizes but 32px are more uniform. If you know how, you can try opening developer tools and inspect these elements.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, and also realised it when I saw the new site logo.

I think it's most probably intended since there're also other sites with a larger logo, such as:

**English Language Learners**

[image: Site 1]

**Magento**

[image: Site 2]

**Music: Practice & Theory**

[image: Site 3]

---

So, it seems like Puzzling isn't the odd one out:

**Puzzling**

[image: Site 4]

Comment: Bah, the ELL icon isn't even the **correct** icon. The App icon and the regular site icons are different.