# Site icons displayed in wrong sizes

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

On the [hot network questions page](https://stackexchange.com/), site icons are showing 48px versions in 32px sizes:

[image]

I know there are 32px versions because I recently posted [another bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284623/various-site-icon-problems) and looked through all of them.

If you replace 48 with 32 in img src, everything will look fine:

[image]

---

As of June 2018 this bug is still not fixed. So I posted my own fix on StackApps: [StackExchange Hot Network Questions page icon size fix](https://stackapps.com/questions/7946/stackexchange-hot-network-questions-page-icon-size-fix)

Comment: This is still the case of today. Thought it would be a quick and easy fix.

Comment: This might have slipped through, bumped it now with an edit.

Comment: *still not fixed* cause nobody cares. Upvoted!

Comment: Temporary fix as userscript: `$('div.hot-question-site-icon span img').each( function() { var i = $(this); i.prop('src',i.prop('src').replace('-48.','-32.'));  });`